# Formal test for the multivariate potential scale reduction factor

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, multivariate-distribution

I'm looking at convergence tests for MCMC sampling, and in particular at the Gelman-Rubin test.

The corrected univariate Gelman-Rubin test has a nice formal test of convergence by assuming $B/W$ (between/within variance) follows an F distribution (Gelman and Rubin (1992)).

However, I fail to find a corresponding test for the multivariate potential scale reduction factor (PSRF).

Is there one?

Common packages (like Coda and Boa in R) does not include a test for the multivariate version of the PSRF, and in their paper, Brooks and Gelman (1998) do not include a format test of convergence for the multivariate version of the statistic.

Can it be assumed that $\lambda_1$ follows an F distribution as well? If $a'Ba$ and $a'Wa$ were independent, their quotient would be F distributed (with a scalar factor). But such an assumption is made in the original test for the univariate statistic as well, isn't it?

If their quotient could be assumed to be F distributed, what would the degrees of freedom be for the numerator and denominator?

### References

Gelman and Rubin (1992). "Inference from Iterative Simulation Using Multiple Sequences". Statistical Science, 7(4): 457-511.

Brooks and Gelman (1998). "General Methods for Monitoring Convergence of Iterative Simulations". Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics, 7(4): 434-455.